# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nz^{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the radius of convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nz^{n!}$ where $a_0=2i$ and $a^2_n=a_{n+1}$

This is not a power series, but if I define $b_k=a_n$ if $k=n!$ for $n \geq 2$ (since $b_0 = 0$ and $b_1=a_1+a_2$) and $b_k=0$ otherwise, I would have a power series such that  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nz^{n!} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} b_kz^{k} $. Noting that $a_n=4^{2^{n-1}}$ therefore nonzero $b_k$'s look like $b_k=4^{2^{n!-1}}$ for some $n \geq 2$.
 Hence $$\frac{1}{R}= \limsup_{k \to \infty} |b_k|^{1/k}=\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(4^{2^{n!-1}}\right)^{1/n!} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} 4^{\frac{2^{n!-1}}{n!}}$$
Since $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n!-1}}{n!} = \infty$ we conclude that the series everywhere diverges.

**Is my reasoning correct ?**

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your definition of $a_n$ does not agree with your later formula for $a_n$, you mix up $k$ and $n$ for your $b_k$, but most importantly, the growth of the $b_k$ gets damped down compared to the $a_k$ while you mistakenly blow them up. I guess that after correcting the errors you want to compare the size of $n!$ and $2^n$, so you will have convergence.

Comment: @Phira I am very sorry !!! I mistyped , I updated the question

the recursive relation is $a^2_n=a_{n+1}$

Comment: @LutzL What do you mean ? that's not true ! It is the other way around !

Comment: Sorry, you changed that faster than I did see it.

Comment: It is a power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=4^{2^{n-1}}$, therefore $b_{n!}=4^{2^{n-1}}$ and the interesting quantitiy for the root test is $(4^{2^{n-1}})^{\frac1{n!}}$. But since $\frac{2^n}{n!}$ goes to $0$, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT ! YES $b_{n!}=a_n$ NOT $a_{n!}$  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your power series looks like $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$, where
$$
b_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
(2i)^{2^k} &\text{if}\,\,n=k!, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Clearly
$$
|b_n|^{1/n}=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
2^{2^k/k!} &\text{if}\,\,n=k!, \\
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and as $2^k/k!\to 0$, then
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|b_n|^{1/n}=1.
$$
which implies that the radius of convergence is $r=1$.

Comment: I am very sorry !!! I mistyped , I updated the question

the recursive relation is $a^2_n=a_{n+1}$

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity: Corrected suitably.